# Read all messages in topic with spring cloud stream

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have few doubts about spring-cloud-stream (using Kafka)....

1. do spring cloud stream have any way to write a consumer which can iterate through all the messages in a topic ? [this basically needed for some validation purpose so that no duplicate messages are written to kafka queue] and,
2. what about the Future/sync support in spring cloud stream like it is in spring-kafka.

if anyone have encountered any such type of scenario's, then can you provide some details about how to achieve them. or I have to use spring-kafka(done through spring-kafka) dependency in parallel to spring-cloud-stream to achieve.

if there are any working code or url's then please provide. this will be really helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am still a bit puzzled about your issues, but just as an FYI, the spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka (which I supposed you are referring to) is dependent on spring-kafka and essentially extends its functionality.